TeXLive portable installation not working
I'm triyng to run install-tl on a USB stick, with -portable option (under MacOS 10.14.6). Yet, the script seems to ignore the option and tries to install on /usr/local/texlive).
What could be the reason? And a possible solution?

@rallg Thanks, in fact I used to have a TeXLive installed on my computer. I uninstalled it some weeks ago, but it's very possible that the paths are still specified. I'll try.
